# How do I configure activity feed to be expanded by default?

Tags: lightning

I was wondering if there was a was a way to configure the Activity feed such that it is expanded by default, with the option to change to compact view if needed. I did some research and wasn't able to find anything on this (also pretty new to Salesforce). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Ashley

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting for this. Consider upvoting the idea asking for this ability: [Expand All by Default on Activity Timeline](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cRcXQAU).

In terms of what you do get, you do have a `Expand All` button users can click on, but they have to click on it for each record.

[image]

For now, if you needed to accomplish this, your only option would be to create a custom [activity timeline](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/activity-timeline/) or leveraging/extending any free custom options on the [appexchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G0yN3UAJ).